# iphone::touchesMoved: Move UIImageView inside UIView?

Tags: uiview, uiimageview, drag

This is my code:

```
- (void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event {

CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
startLocation = pt;
[super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
CGRect frame = [self.view frame];
frame.origin.x += pt.x - startLocation.x;
frame.origin.y += pt.y - startLocation.y;
[self.view setFrame:frame];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];


UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"boo2.png"]];
imv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
[v addSubview:imv];

[self.view addSubview: v];
[v release];

UIView *v2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
v2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];


UIImageView *imv2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"boo2.png"]];
imv2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
[v2 addSubview:imv2];

[self.view addSubview: v2];
[v2 release];
}
```

What I want to do is to move the UIImageView inside the UIView, not the entire view. But, the code above, when I try to drag, it moves the entire view.

NOTE: The images are return from others functions, not declared in viewdidload. Assume, you cant declare UIImageView variables.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do. and I don't know why you put each of the `UIImageView's` inside a `UIView` which you put into the view controller's view. You can just as well add the `UIImageView's` as sub-views of the view controller's view directly.

Nevertheless, from what I can make out it looks like the user must be able to drag the images on the screen around.

If this is the case, I would suggest that you store each one of the `UIImageView's` in an array. Then, in `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, you will have to determine which `UIImageView` is being touched. Getting the `CGPoint` representing the location in the main view, as you do in your code, is a good start. If you added the `UIImageView's` directly as sub-views of the main view, you can then compare the coordinates of this `CGPoint` with the frames of these `UIImageView's` to determine which one is being pressed.

Then, to allow dragging, you need to save the coordinates of the `UIImageView` at the beginning of the touch. Then, everytime the touch moves, you can compute the new x-position of the `UIImageView` as the original x-position, plus the distance moved. That is,

`newImageViewX = imageViewStartX + (newTouchX - touchStartX);`

and similarly for the y-position.